# Как сделать чтобы ссылки слева закрепить?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-сайт, стилизация

```
<body>
<div class="head">
    <div class="head-title">FORUM</div>
    <div class="head-title"><a href="#">Новая запись</a></div>
    <div class="sign"><a style="margin-right: 20px;" class="head-title" href="#">Войти</a></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="left">
        <ul>
            <a href="#">Статьи</a>
            <a href="#">Записи</a>
            <a href="#">Видео</a>
            <a href="#">Популяное</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
            домашних условиях. При создании генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст
            генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать
            текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="news">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
        </div>
        <div class="news">
            Смысл сайта
            Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее
            осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

````
body
    margin: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 235, 235);
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;

h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

a
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;

.head
    display: flex;
    padding: 15px;
    background: rgb(180, 180, 180); /* Цвет фона */
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,1); /* Параметры тени */
    padding: 15px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 2em;
    min-height: 2em;

.head-title
    margin-left: 25px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;

.sign
    margin-left: auto;

.left
    margin-right: 100px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 2;

.center
    margin-right: 50px;
    max-width: 60%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Сomic Sans MS;
    font-weight: 600;

.right
    max-width: 20%;
    margin-right: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Courier New;
    font-weight: 600;

.main
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;

.content
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;

.news
    margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    border-radius: 10px;```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.left ul {
position: sticky;
top: 100px;
}
```

```css
.left ul {
  position: sticky;
  top: 100px;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 235, 235);
  letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.head {
  display: flex;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgb(180, 180, 180);
  /* Цвет фона */
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  /* Параметры тени */
  padding: 15px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 2em;
  min-height: 2em;
}

.head-title {
  margin-left: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sign {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.left {
  margin-right: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 2;
}

.center {
  margin-right: 50px;
  max-width: 60%;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Сomic Sans MS;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.right {
  max-width: 20%;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.main {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.news {
  margin: 50px 0px 50px 0px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
  <div class="head-title">FORUM</div>
  <div class="head-title"><a href="#">Новая запись</a></div>
  <div class="sign"><a style="margin-right: 20px;" class="head-title" href="#">Войти</a></div>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <a href="#">Статьи</a>
      <a href="#">Записи</a>
      <a href="#">Видео</a>
      <a href="#">Популяное</a>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="center">
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в домашних условиях. При создании
      генератора мы использовали небезизвестный универсальный код речей. Текст генерируется абзацами случайным образом от двух до десяти предложений в абзаце, что позволяет сделать текст более привлекательным и живым для визуально-слухового восприятия.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="news">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
    </div>
    <div class="news">
      Смысл сайта Сайт рыбатекст поможет дизайнеру, верстальщику, вебмастеру сгенерировать несколько абзацев более менее осмысленного текста рыбы на русском языке, а начинающему оратору отточить навык публичных выступлений в
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать для блока .left `position:fixed;`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]